# Converting my Application Theme to Lollipop

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I am currently working on some changes to my app to properly target the new Android 5.0 Lollipop that has just been released.

I have the following in my styles.xml files in the values-v21 directory

```
<resources>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/actionBarTabStyle</item>
        <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/white</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:background">@color/appPrimaryColour</item>
    </style>

    <style name="actionBarTabStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabText">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

I've changed the theme but I have customised my action bar with the following for the old Holo theme

`<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">`

and

`<style name="actionBarTabStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabText">`

I can't find what the equivalent would be for Lollipop, I've tried `@android:style/Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse` `@android:style/Widget.Material.ActionBar.TabText"` but it then says it can't find the resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just extend from Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar, which sets up the action bar theme to point to Theme.Material (dark) values for background and foreground colors. Also, you should be setting colorPrimary, colorPrimaryDark, and colorAccent in your AppTheme rather than manually setting the action bar background color.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/appPrimaryColour</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark"> ... </item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent"> ... </item>
</style>
```

Comment: If you use AppCompat, it looks something like:  `<style name="AppTheme"
        parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">  <item name="colorPrimary">@color/MyPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/MyPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/MyColorAccent</item></style>`  Notice that you get rid of the "`android:`" prefix... and this can be in your regular `/res/values`/ directory- no need for a `values-v21` because it's picked up for older versions of Android as well.  Seems to work for me, anyway.

Comment: I'll extend the above answer to note that Google just blogged about the new stuff supported in AppCompat:  http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html